# PHP Composer autoload

Tags: .htaccess, composer-php, fat-free-framework, psr-4

I code with fat-free-framework and I try use this structure

```
app/
vendor/
public/
   index.php
```

composer.json

```
{
   "require": {
      "bcosca/fatfree": "^3.7"
   },
   "autoload": {
      "psr-4": { "App\\": "app/" }
   }
}
```

with local server **php -S 127.0.0.1:8000 -t public/** my site is displayed correctly but is a deploy on remote server with a subdomain.domain.com I have classic error

```
HTTP 404 (GET /test)

[hb/vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/base.php:1716] Base->error()
[hb/public/index.php:34] Base->run()
```

if I try to call a class in my namespace App I have an error
**Internal Server Error**

```
Class 'App\Test' not found [/home/clients/zzz/web/test/public/index.php:26]

[/home/clients/zzz/web/test/vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/base.php:1955] {closure}()
[/home/clients/zzz/web/test/vendor/bcosca/fatfree/lib/base.php:1754] Base->call()
[index.php:35] Base->run()
```

my .htaccess in folder public with index.php is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(app|tmp)\/|\.ini$ - [R=404]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

thank you all

Comment: Please share more details. You haven't provided any code for `App\Test`, so it looks pretty obvious to me that this error message is shown

Comment: thank you with "composer dump-autoload -o" I suppose the problem is uppercase or lower case in the folder name: app/ app/Test.php app/Controller/Test2.php

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: If you're using httpd for your webserver, is `AllowOverride All` turned on? Otherwise it won't even look at your htaccess file.

Comment: In your layout.htm or container html page, you should have a tag for declaring your base url `<base href="https://www.example.com/">`. That should help with setting the base urls for your links, images, stylesheets, etc.

Answer (score 0):

in your public/index.php, change the current working dir back to the project root path before doing anything else: `chdir('../');`

that should fix it.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - **why** should this help? Is there any reason that the existing code works without that on one system, but not on the other?